How to prevent child from rotating with parent during the transition?
I'm trying to rotate a parent circle and negate the effect on its children.
I tried to negate the effect by using
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
           rotate(calc(var(--i) * -60deg))
           translateY(150px)
           rotate(calc(var(--i) * 60deg - var(--rotation)))

but the children will rotate 60deg at the start of the transition. How to prevent them from rotating completely duration the transition?


const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
let deg = 0;

function rotate() {
  deg += 60;
  circle.style.cssText = `--rotation: ${deg}deg`;
}
.circle {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  transition: transform 1000ms ease;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(calc(var(--i) * -60deg)) translateY(150px) rotate(calc(var(--i) * 60deg - var(--rotation)));
  width: 30px;
}

.btn {
  align-items: center;
  background: lawngreen;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
}
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class="circle" id="circle" style="--rotation: 0deg">
  <div class="item" style="--i: 0">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 1">2</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 2">3</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 3">4</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 4">5</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 5">6</div>
</div>

<div class='btn' onclick="rotate()">rotate</div>




You are almost there, simply add the same transition to the child elements


const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
let deg = 0;

function rotate() {
  deg += 60;
  circle.style.cssText = `--rotation: ${deg}deg`;
}
.circle {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  transition: transform 1000ms ease;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(calc(var(--i) * -60deg)) translateY(150px) rotate(calc(var(--i) * 60deg - var(--rotation)));
  transition: transform 1000ms ease;
  width: 30px;
}

.btn {
  align-items: center;
  background: lawngreen;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
}
<div class="circle" id="circle" style="--rotation: 0deg">
  <div class="item" style="--i: 0">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 1">2</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 2">3</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 3">4</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 4">5</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 5">6</div>
</div>

<div class='btn' onclick="rotate()">rotate</div>






const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
let deg = 0;

function rotate() {
  deg += 60;
  circle.style.setProperty('--rotation', `${deg}deg`);
}
.circle {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 40px auto 0;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
  transition: transform 1000ms ease;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.item {
  align-items: center;
  background: red;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(calc(var(--i) * 60deg)) translateY(150px);
  /* Position around circle */
  width: 30px;
}

.btn {
  align-items: center;
  background: lawngreen;
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
<div class="circle" id="circle" style="--rotation: 0deg">
  <div class="item" style="--i: 0">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 1">2</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 2">3</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 3">4</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 4">5</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 5">6</div>
</div>
<div class="btn" onclick="rotate()">Rotate</div>




Please also explain with words what you did

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
